# How can i add a Custom Translation Middleware to Bot Composer in node js

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I looked in the below documentation but was not clear on how to add the middleware in node js template for bot composer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-extend-with-code

Please if anyone can help in achieving the same.

Needs guidance on same

Answer (score 0):

To implement a multilingual chatbot, developers typically use natural language processing (NLP) techniques to detect the language being used by the user and then respond in that language.

You can do this by installing nuget package.

[For video reference you can watch here.](https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/BotTutorialSample/tree/master/BotComposer/34-MultilingualBot/MultilingualBot)